# Python is unable to locate a file on my desktop

Tags: python, file

So I am working on a problem set in a MIT Free Course. The problem is to create a word game and I have downloaded a list of 84,000 words that will serve as a dictionary. The file is located in my desktop and I have tried entering the specific location in PyCharm but for some reason it can not find the file. I have tried storing the file in different places and forms but it can not locate it. Here is the error traceback:

```
File "/Users/ksorenson/PycharmProjects/Word Game/ps5cheat_sheet.py", line 241, in <module>
    word_list = load_words()

File "/Users/ksorenson/PycharmProjects/Word Game/ps5cheat_sheet.py", line 33, in load_words
    inFile = open(WORDLIST_FILENAME, 'r', 0)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'words.txt'
```

Here is some of the code:

```
# Problem Set 5: 6.00 Word Game
# Name:
# Collaborators:
# Time:
#

import random
import string

VOWELS = 'aeiou'
CONSONANTS = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'
HAND_SIZE = 7

SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES = {
    'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'f': 4, 'g': 2, 'h': 4, 'i': 1, 'j': 8, 'k': 5, 'l': 1, 'm': 3, 'n': 1, 'o': 1, 'p': 3, 'q': 10, 'r': 1, 's': 1, 't': 1, 'u': 1, 'v': 4, 'w': 4, 'x': 8, 'y': 4, 'z': 10
}

# -----------------------------------
# Helper code
# (you don't need to understand this helper code)

WORDLIST_FILENAME = "words.txt"  *************HERE IS THE FILE THAT I CANNOT LOCATE*********

def load_words():
    """
    Returns a list of valid words. Words are strings of lowercase letters.

    Depending on the size of the word list, this function may
    take a while to finish.
    """
    print("Loading word list from file...")
    # inFile: file
    inFile = open(WORDLIST_FILENAME, 'r', 0)
    # wordlist: list of strings
    wordlist = []
    for line in inFile:
        wordlist.append(line.strip().lower())
    print("  ", len(wordlist), "words loaded.")
    return wordlist
```

Comment: you never tell it its on your desktop. The variable puts it in the same directory as your script which appears to be your home folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
import os
WORDLIST_FILENAME = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/words.txt")
```

Comment: So, stupid mistake, I opened the file and was able to find the location and use that.  New problem, Error message says: ValueError: can't have unbuffered text I/O

Comment: I think the issue is that the file was written in python 2 and I am currently running python 3.3. . .and there are too many changes between the two that are not backwards compatible :(

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Cfreak.  It's trying to open `words.txt`, which it interprets to be a relative path, and, because there are not directory specifications in the path, the script expects to be in the current working directory (often the same one as the script).  Either modify the script the way wim suggests or move `words.txt` into the same directory as the script.

Comment: Relative paths are relative to the current working directory, not the location of the script.